# Tensorflow and Keras can't be used or updated with Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I installed the packages for Tensorflow and Keras by using the Anaconda Packege installer (I have a separate environment for that). Unfortunately I can't use Tensorflow or Keras. When I use the following code, I get an error message:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

zip_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    origin='https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip',
    fname='jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip',
    extract=True)
csv_path, _ = os.path.splitext(zip_path)
```

--> Error message: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'

I tried to check the version of tensorflow by using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

--> Error message: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '**version**'

I checked in the package manager of Anaconda and there the version of Tensorflow is 2.1.0 (see Screenshot)[image]
From this website I can see that there is in fact a version 2.2 (https://docs.floydhub.com/guides/environments/)
However, I tried to update tensorflow (such that I can use it with keras) by using

```
Conda update tensorflow
```

But this did not change anything. I get the message: "# All requested packages already installed." and problem still persists and the version number remained unchanged. Also trying

```
Conda update keras
```

yields the same message "# All requested packages already installed."

What am I doing wrong? I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thankful for your help.

Comment: Have you created a file called `tensorflow.py` by any chance? Try `import tensorflow;print(tensorflow)`. What does it give you?

Comment: Thanks FlyingTeller for your answer. What do you mean by "creating a tensorflow.py". I have just installed Anaconda and used the package manager to import Tensorflow and Keras. I did not do anything else exclicitly. If I use the code "import tensorflow as tf, print(tf)" I get the following output: "runfile('C:/Users/wi9632/bwSyncShare3/Eigene Arbeit/Code/Python/Time_Series_Forecasting.py', wdir='C:/Users/wi9632/bwSyncShare3/Eigene Arbeit/Code/Python')
<module 'tensorflow' from 'C:\\Users\\wi9632\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Keras\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\__init__.py'>"

Comment: That looks like the right path from where it loads `tensorflow` (from the environment `Keras`). If you had a file called `tensorflow.py` in your working directory, then `import tensorflow` would load that file instead of the actual module, which would have explained your error. Unfortunately it is not the case. Can you try to create a fresh env with `conda create -n tf tensorflow=2.1`, then do `conda activate tf` and `python -c "import tensorflow;import tensorflow.keras`? Just to check that your installation of tensorflow is not broken

Comment: Thanks FlyingTeller for your further comment. Basically your suggested way helped me solve the problem :-). I really appreciate your help (if you post this as a real answer not just a comment I will upvote and accept it). Thanks again.

Comment: Glad i could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure that your tf installation is not shadowed**

(only for future readers, as it was not your issue) make sure that nothing is shadowing your actual `tensorflow` installation (i.e. a file called tensorflow.py that is in your PYTHONPATH) by running

```
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow)
```

which should result in a path `site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py`

**Try reinstalling tf in a fresh environment**

Just to make sure that your current installation is not broken:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow 
conda activate tf
python -c "import tensorflow;import tensorflow.keras"
```

If this works, then your original installation was broken in some way

Comment: Thanks FlyingTeller for your answer (I upvoted and accepted it). Basically your solution works. However, I still can't update tensorflow. At the moment I have version 2.1.0 (as seen in the screenshot above) and I would like to update it as version 2.1.0 does not have a special attribute and yields the following error "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.preprocessing' has no attribute'timeseries_dataset_from_array'". When using "Conda update tensorflow" nothing really happens as it yields the same message "# All requested packages already installed."

Comment: By default `conda` should have isntalled the most recent version that is compatible with your setup. This is the behaviour you see in the newly created environment? Can you try `conda install tensorflow==2.3` in the newly created environment?

Comment: Thanks FlyingTeller. Your suggestion helped and solved the problem :-). I really appreciate your effort and tremendous help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help